# Let $n\geq 3$. Is there a connected, planar, bipartite graph with $n$ regions and $n$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

The answer given is that according to a Corollary of Euler’s formula (Corollary 3 Section 10.7), such a graph has at most $2n − 4$ edges. Applying this to Euler’s formula ($r = m − n + 2$), there are at
most $r = 2n − 4 − n + 2 = n − 2$ regions. My question is, when do we use $m ≤ 2n-4$ and $m ≤ 3n-6$? Why can we not use the second formula here? (Here, $m$ refers to edges and $n$ refers to vertices.)

Comment: Indeed, you can use the constraint $m\le 3n - 6$, but for your specific problem, you won't derive a contradiction. Then, you need to further contemplate whether such  connected planar bipartite graph exists or not. For **any** simple (not necessarily connected) planar graph (actually, it doesn't have to be simple as long as there are no 1-faces or 2-faces), it holds that $m \le 3n - 6$. However, for bipartite graphs, we have the stronger constraint: every face has degree more than 4. This way, directly stating that the desired graphs do not exist, why not use the better tool?